# How can I add a small UIView(Something like a pop-up window) on existing View?

Tags: iphone, subview

I want to add a Customized UIView that will take Text input from user. I tried this by creating a new UIViewController which can take text input. But when I Navigation Controller to show this View it occupies entire screen. I don't want entire screen to be covered by new view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an UIAlertView and add text fields to it? Or declare a UIView in your .h file, and link it in the XIB file, then when the user needs to be brought to this view:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:textFieldView];
```

And you are still in the same view, so you can always go back to the original view itself:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:textFieldView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[parentView addSubview:smallView]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) to take user input, it shows an view like `UIAlertView` but with an `UITextField`